# Non ascii in Sonar profile name

Tags: maven, utf-8, sonarqube

I want to build a sonar dashboard in my firm for an audience wider than the developer circle. So I want to use french labels, for example use the word "Règle" instead of "Rule".

But the accented character is misspelled as unresolved utf-8 « RÃ¨gles » and can not be adressed from maven sonar plugin :

in pom.xml:

```
<sonar.profile>Règles XXXX</sonar.profile>
```

In console:

```
[INFO] Quality profile for java: RÃ¨gles XXXX
.../...
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar (default-cli) on project xxxx: sonar.profile was set to 'Règles XXXX' but didn't match any profile for any language. Please check your configuration. -> [Help 1]
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: you could change "Règles" in your pom by `R&#xE8;gles` (UTF-8 encoding)

Comment: What encoding does your pom.xml specify in its xml-header? What is its actual encoding?

Comment: Standard encoding, utf8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably affected by this issue:
https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-8428

There is currently no fix, so you should rename your profile to not contain non ascii characters.

Answer (score 3):

You're not "specifying" the profile in the pom, you're *overriding* it.

In the SonarQube UI, simply set Règles XXXX as the default profile or assign the relevant projects to it, and remove that property from your pom.

Note also that there's a French localization plugin, but it's a bit out of date.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Note that I face the same problem in Sonar UI, even though the french plugin is installed. But it's true I don't have to specify the profile name in pom.xml.